# GCC -static build creates the executable of different sizes on different machines

Tags: linux, gcc, build

I am creating an executable using gcc. I am building with the static option so that there are no package issues. But when I build the executable using same code, and same command on a different machine, its size is different (one is about 3MB and other is about 19MB). I know the `-static` will copy all the library functions required to the executable file but if the code is same so how can the size of library functions copied be different on different machines?

Does the file size of the executable built statically depends on the system and how like what's the reasoning? How can I justify why second system produces a larger executable, I mean what should I search for?

Comment: Why is your Linux GCC build producing a Windows `.exe`? Is this mingw?

Comment: I am sorry @thatotherguy to write the .exe I just wanted to say the executable or binary. it is a linux system only, not windows.

Comment: In principle it is unsurprising that "the same" static build produces non-identical executables on different machines. Without concrete details the possibilities are wearisome. Useful answers are more likely if you edit your post to include at least: The output of `uname -a` and of `gcc --version -v` for each machine; a minimal example program that reproduces the effect; the sequence of commands, verbatim, used to build the example program, plus their complete output. In the course of devising your minimal example program there is a fair chance you will discover the answer yourself!

Comment: If all the binaries are properly stripped then I would look at the libc on each system. glibc will result in larger static binaries than uclibc. I'd also also look at whether they're compiled with `-ffunction-sections`